# Generating a table based on an array of objects

Tags: javascript, react.js

I have a React component that generates a table based on an array of objects, which gets populated with data in an object.

I'm trying to learn as much as I can about React.js / JavaScript. Could anyone with more experience in this area show me a way to simplify the code that I have here? Or if there are any other 'fancy' ways of doing what is being done in the code?

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Table from './Table';

//Columns defines table headings and properties to be placed into the body
let columns = [
  {
    heading: 'Name',
    property: 'name'
  },
  {
    heading: 'Age',
    property: 'age'
  },
  {
    heading: 'Sex',
    property: 'sex'
  },
  {
    heading: 'Breed',
    property: 'breed'
  },
]

//Data is the array of objects to be placed into the table
let data = [
  {
    name: 'Sabrina',
    age: '6',
    sex: 'Female',
    breed: 'Staffordshire'
  },
  {
    name: 'Max',
    age: '2',
    sex: 'Male',
    breed: 'Boxer'
  }
]

class App extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          data={data}
          propertyAsKey='name' //The data property to be used as a key
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Table.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Table extends Component {

  buildTable = (columns, data, key) => {
    let headerRow = [];
    let dataRows = [];

    //Build the table header
    columns.forEach (col => {
      headerRow.push(
        <th key={`header-${col.heading}`}>{col.heading}</th>
      );
    });

    //Build the rows
    data.forEach(item => {
      let dataCells = [];

      //Build cells for this row
      columns.forEach (col => {
        dataCells.push(
          <td key={`${item[key]}-${col.property}`}>{item[col.property]}</td>
        );
      });

      //Push out row
      dataRows.push(
        <tr key={`${item[key]}-row`}>{dataCells}</tr>
      )
    });

    return(
      <>
        <thead>
          <tr>{headerRow}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {dataRows}
        </tbody>
      </>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const {
      columns,
      data,
      propertyAsKey
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <table className='table'>
        {this.buildTable(columns, data, propertyAsKey)}
      </table>
    );
  }
}

export default Table;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR Fully functionnal example :

```js
//Columns defines table headings and properties to be placed into the body
const columns = [{ heading: 'Name', property: 'name' }, { heading: 'Age', property: 'age' }, { heading: 'Sex', property: 'sex' }, { heading: 'Breed', property: 'breed' },]

//Data is the array of objects to be placed into the table
const data = [{ name: 'Sabrina', age: '6', sex: 'Female', breed: 'Staffordshire' }, { name: 'Max', age: '2', sex: 'Male', breed: 'Boxer' }]

const App = props => <Table columns={columns} data={data} propertyAsKey='name' />

const Table = ({ columns, data, propertyAsKey }) => 
    <table className='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>{columns.map(col => <th key={`header-${col.heading}`}>{col.heading}</th>)}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {data.map(item =>
                <tr key={`${item[propertyAsKey]}-row`}>
                    {columns.map(col => <td key={`${item[propertyAsKey]}-${col.property}`}>{item[col.property]}</td>)}
                </tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'>
```

---

The main thing that would highly reduce this code is the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. This function can be applied on an array, execute a callback on every item in the array and returns a new array.

By using it you can reduce the following code :

```
let headerRow = [];

columns.forEach(col => {
    headerRow.push(
        <th key={`header-${col.heading}`}>{col.heading}</th>
    );
});
```

Can be reduced to this with the exact same result :

```
const headerRow = columns.map(col => <th key={`header-${col.heading}`}>{col.heading}</th>)
```

You can now include this function directly into your JSX :

```
<thead>
    <tr>{columns.map(col => <th key={`header-${col.heading}`}>{col.heading}</th>)}</tr>
</thead>
```

And the same thing with nested mapping for the body :

```
<tbody>
    {data.map(item => 
        <tr key={`${item[key]}-row`}>
            {columns.map(col => <td key={`${item[key]}-${col.property}`}>{item[col.property]}</td>)}
        </tr>
    )}
</tbody>
```

Your full `buildTable` function is now reduced to the following :

```
buildTable = (columns, data, key) => {
    return (
        <>
            <thead>
                <tr>{columns.map(col => <th key={`header-${col.heading}`}>{col.heading}</th>)}</tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {data.map(item => 
                    <tr key={`${item[key]}-row`}>
                        {columns.map(col => <td key={`${item[key]}-${col.property}`}>{item[col.property]}</td>)}
                    </tr>
                )}
            </tbody>
        </>
    );
};
```

If you want to go a little further you can also delete this function and embed this code in your `render` function JSX. I will also convert your component into a stateless function, since you are not using any state value :

```
const Table = ({ columns, data, propertyAsKey }) => //Deconstructs your props
    <table className='table'>
        <thead>
            <tr>{columns.map(col => <th key={`header-${col.heading}`}>{col.heading}</th>)}</tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {data.map(item =>
                <tr key={`${item[propertyAsKey]}-row`}>
                    {columns.map(col => <td key={`${item[propertyAsKey]}-${col.property}`}>{item[col.property]}</td>)}
                </tr>
            )}
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

(You may add brackets and a `return` statement after the arrow sign, its up to you)

It is also not required to have a fragment as a parent element in your `render`, as long as there is a single element, it is fine :

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Table
          columns={columns}
          data={data}
          propertyAsKey='name' //The data property to be used as a key
        />
    );
  }
}
```

Your `App` component could also be converted to a stateless component:

```
const App = props => <Table columns={columns} data={data} propertyAsKey='name' />
```